# SIGSTOP a task while in disk sleep in own kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, scheduler, coredump

I'm currently developing a crash collection mechanism that uses a custom core format. In essence it hooks the linux_binfmt->core_dump entries to point to our dumper.

The dumper itself launches a usermode helper with the PID of the process to capture which dumps the process information via ptrace before allowing the kernel to fully kill the process:

```
call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);
```

My issue is that the task is technically in a disk sleep state and not stopped so ptrace calls fail.

I attempted to SEND_SIG_FORCED a SIGSTOP to no avail:

```
send_sig_info(SIGSTOP, SEND_SIG_FORCED, current);
```

Any advice on how to still block the termination of the process but place it in a stopped state to get the ptrace usermode collector working would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution due in part to some inconsistent flags checking in ptrace:

```
printk(KERN_INFO "%s Launching usermode helper for %d\n", __FUNCTION__, current->pid);

call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_NO_WAIT);
set_current_state(TASK_UNINTERRUPTIBLE | TASK_TRACED);
schedule();

printk(KERN_INFO "%s user-mode helper done! killing pid %d\n", __FUNCTION__, current->pid);
```

This places the task in trace sleep state and the helper can then attach to it.